# QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene total size

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QGraphicsView` and disposed thereon `QGraphicsScene`. On stage I have placed `QGraphicsItem`, and checks the output items for view-border widget thus:

```
 if(!(ui->area->sceneRect().contains((ui->area->mapFromScene(item->boundingRect())).boundingRect()))){...}
```

My problem is that the scene exceeds the size of the widget, ie items can be moved beyond the boundaries of the visible widget. Then, crossing event is triggered, which means that the scene is still limited rectangle.

I set the scene as follows:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :QMainWindow(parent),  ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
        scene= new QGraphicsScene(ui->area);
        scene->setSceneRect(0,0,ui->area->size().width(),ui-area->size().height());
        scene->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt::black)); 
        ui -> area -> setRenderHints ( QPainter :: Antialiasing
                         |  QPainter :: SmoothPixmapTransform
                         |  QPainter :: TextAntialiasing );
        ui->area-setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::BoundingRectViewportUpdate); 
        ui->area-setCacheMode(QGraphicsView::CacheBackground);
        ui->area-setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing,false); 
        ui->area->setInteractive(true); ui-area-setScene(scene);
        ui->area->setScene(scene);
       .... 

}
```

What is my error?
P.S. More will be grateful for advice on how you can implement the resize widget (with the scene), when resizing the main window? Widget is located in `QHBoxLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your custom class which inherits from QGraphicsView.  You should reimplement resizeEvent( QResizeEvent *event ) in your custom QGraphicsView like:

```
void MyView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{

    fitInView(0, 0, 500, 500,Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

    QGraphicsView::resizeEvent(event);
}
```

This way the view will always display the whole scene. I.e. if the window size is changed and the graphicsView is resized, The scene gets scaled and you can see everything appropriately.

Comment: I inherited from `QGraphicsView` and implemented `void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *);`, but the size of the stage is still larger than the widget.